Should [attack] and [attacks] be synonyms?
There are two distinct tags [attack] (with 2 questions) and [attacks] (with 5 questions).  Should we merge these?
Update: Tags have been merged

Yeah, I think we should merge them. Can't see how they could be used for different things.

Yes. Definitely. There is no imaginable difference. (I just submitted a merge request.)
Update: Please vote on my tag synonym request!

Where can we vote?

With sufficient rep, you should be able to vote on on the tag synonyms page.

According to the privilages page, I already have sufficient permission - yet I didn't find anywhere to vote in the page you linked to.

Ahh, you have to click on attack and then vote up attacks.

Ah, I see. I don't have the required score on the tag page to vote. Also can you please tag me (@ripper234, no pun intended) if you want me to see your comment, on a question that I didn't ask?
